# Bibliography does not update

Tags: bibliographies, winedt, updating

I am using WinEdt to write my thesis and JabRef for the bibliography and encounter the following problem:
Whenever I change or add something to my list in JabRef and use the "PDFTeXify" button to compile from WinEdt to PDF, the new information is not passed along. There is a cumbersome solution: I open a new file in WinEdt, with a new name, and copy and paste everything from my original file, then compile. However, this only works once and is extremely annoying.

Does anyone know, what is happening here and how to fix it?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: You need to run `bibtex` (or `biber`) too.

Comment: Don't use texify when there is a problem. It is a pain to debug. Run the tools manually.

Comment: Thank you for your input - can you also explain to me, how I do run the tools manually?
I have used the Texify button in a dozen other papers I wrote and it always worked fine, so any new approach to me is breaking new ground ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm afraid this is a bug introduced in WinEdt version 10.2.

A new build will be released before the end of the year with this correction.

For the moment, do the following:

1. Show the "Options Interface" (Options -> Options Interface)

   [image]
2. In the interface, go to "Advanced Configuration" -> "Compile Macros" and double-click the "PDFTeXify" item (`PDFTeXify.edt` gets opened)
3. Search for the lines

   ```
     IfNum("%!3","%$(!'Max-TeXify-Iterations');",!"<",>
       !|Exe('%b\Exec\TeX\BibTeXify.edt');|);
   ```

   and replace them with

   ```
     IfNum("%$(!'Max-TeXify-Iterations');",!"0",!">",>
       !|Exe('%b\Exec\TeX\BibTeXify.edt');|);
   ```
4. Save the file.
5. Now (in the "Options Interface") double-click the "TeXify" item (`TeXify.edt` gets opened) and repeat steps 3 and 4 for this file.

That's all. Now your changes to the bibliography will be seen by WinEdt.

Comment: Great answer, love the screenshot and step-by-step explanation. Only space for improvement I can think of is to clarify that the second code line is redundant.

Awesome work, thank you very much!